# Ubuntu 16.04LTS hibernation prolem

Tags: 16.04

When I close the lip of my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04LTS , the system doesn't sleep or hibernate. My battery drains cause of this issue..
What am I supposed to do ??

Comment: Is it same when you click on suspend item in the top-right menu?

Comment: Can you hibernate from Terminal  sudo pm-hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Go to system settings-> Power and
When the lid is closed -> suspend